# Segfault in std::atomic load?

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, atomic

On linux, using gcc 4.8.4, compiled with -std=c++11 -mcx16:

```
#include <atomic>

struct node_t;

struct pointer_t {
        node_t* ptr;
        unsigned int count;
        pointer_t() noexcept : ptr{nullptr}, count{0} {}
};

struct empty {};

struct node_t {
        empty value;
        std::atomic<pointer_t> next;
        node_t() : next{pointer_t{}} {}
};

int main() {
        node_t{}.next.load();
        return 0;
}
```

gives a segfault when `load` is called. How am I meant to initialize an atomic value?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the `_t` suffix is reserved on POSIX systems.

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `pointer_t::load()` anywhere...

Comment: @BetaCarotin yeah, I'm just directly translating  https://www.cs.rochester.edu/research/synchronization/pseudocode/queues.html :)

Comment: @Kevin I'm calling load on a `std::atomic<pointer_t>`, not on a `pointer_t`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out this is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65147) in gcc that has since been fixed in GCC 5.1. Specifying the alignment to be two words fixed it.

Comment: @Drew Dormann : Is there any patch/solution that could avoid this in gcc 4.8.4 itself?

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil Yes, you need to specify the alignment of the pointer to be two words.

Comment: I was accidentally changing the base class object address, so it was appearing that atomic data member variable was allocated on the odd address. thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am just wondering if this bug has been fixed in default gcc compiler of CentOS 7.3?

Comment: How to specify the alignment to be two words, an example? Thanks

Comment: See the alignas keyword